# How Python lookup modules and method

Tags: python, python-3.x

For linux installation environment, Python standard modules are mostly stored at the path '**/usr/lib64/python3x/**' as a single .py file. (I am using version 3.6 and Centos 6 here) All of the available method and classes should be found in that single .py file.

Take the module '**datetime**' for example, in the docs it says it has a class called '**date**', and for this class it has a method called '**today()**'. So in '**/usr/lib64/python3.6/datetime.py**' we can found

```
class date:
..
..
    def today(cls):
    ..
    ..
```

However, for the module 'ssl', in '**/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py**', in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) there are this method called '**SSLContext.cert_store_stats()**', but in the file 'ssl.py', I can find the class **SSLContext**, but I can't seems to find the method **cert_store_stats()** in that class. Why is that so ?

This is not for any code issue, just out of curiosity of how Python lookup its module and method.

Comment: But this is just standard inheritance. That file shows that SSLContext inherits from _SSLContext, which is a class implemented directly in C in the _ssl module, and which provides that method.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the ssl.py source, the very first lines states:

```
# Wrapper module for _ssl, providing some additional facilities
# implemented in Python.
```

Then a bit further down (after the module's docstring), you'll find

```
from _ssl import _SSLContext
```

and finally the `SSLContext` class definition starting with:

```
class SSLContext(_SSLContext):
```

IOW, the method you're looking for is inherited from `_ssl._SSLContext`.

NB : `_ssl` is a C-coded module, and you'll find a couple other in the stdlib and 3rd part apps.

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielRoseman pointed out in the comments, [`SLLContext` inherits from `_SLLContext` in `ssl.ply`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/ssl.py#L383):

```
class SSLContext(_SSLContext):
```

And `_SLLContext` is located in `_ssl.c`. If you look around, you can see that [in `_ssl.c` `_SSLContext.cert_store_stats` is defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f2f55e7f03d332fd43bc665a86d585a79c3b3ed4/Modules/_ssl.c#L4449):

```
static PyObject *
_ssl__SSLContext_cert_store_stats_impl(PySSLContext *self)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=5f356f4d9cca874d input=eb40dd0f6d0e40cf]*/
{
    X509_STORE *store;
    STACK_OF(X509_OBJECT) *objs;
    X509_OBJECT *obj;
    int x509 = 0, crl = 0, ca = 0, i;

    store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(self->ctx);
    objs = X509_STORE_get0_objects(store);
    for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_OBJECT_num(objs); i++) {
        obj = sk_X509_OBJECT_value(objs, i);
        switch (X509_OBJECT_get_type(obj)) {
            case X509_LU_X509:
                x509++;
                if (X509_check_ca(X509_OBJECT_get0_X509(obj))) {
                    ca++;
                }
                break;
            case X509_LU_CRL:
                crl++;
                break;
            default:
                /* Ignore X509_LU_FAIL, X509_LU_RETRY, X509_LU_PKEY.
                 * As far as I can tell they are internal states and never
                 * stored in a cert store */
                break;
        }
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("{sisisi}", "x509", x509, "crl", crl,
        "x509_ca", ca);
}
```

Because `SSLContext` inheirts from `_SSLContext`, `SLLContext` has access to the method `cert_store_stats`.